# Evaluating the improvement in goodness-of-fit (power function fits)

Tags: goodness-of-fit, power-law

Imagine an experiment where 15 participants are presented with pictures. Each picture is presented 8 times (within-subject design). We want to evaluate the effect of picture repetition (independent variable; 8 levels: 1st repetition, 2nd repetition ... 8th repetition) on reaction time (RT), and on the amplitude (in microvolts) of electroencephalographic components called N400 and CDA (so we have 3 dependent variables DVs). 
On average, N400, CDA, and RT datapoints (8 datapoints) follow a power law. Interestingly, the exponent parameter (learning rate) seems to be similar across the 3 DVs. We want to test this hypothesis. 
My idea is to fit 2 power function models to data. In the first model, all parameters are free to vary for each DV. In the second model, the exponent is constrained to be similar across the 3 DVs. I 'd like to perform a formal comparison of the goodness-of-fit from the 2 models. How can I do that?